# How to filter windows event log with wildcard?

Tags: windows-event-log, eventviewer, xml

According to the document [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd996910(v=vs.85).aspx#limitations), the asterisk wildcard is supported and hence it should work in eg.

*[EventData[Data[@Name='TargetUserName'] ='User1*']]

but I cannot get any wildcard filter to work - has anyone been able to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The XPath selector must begin with *, however you cannot use * to filter fields as Xpath 1.0 has no `contains` operator.

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askds/2011/09/26/advanced-xml-filtering-in-the-windows-event-viewer/

> XPath 1.0 Limitations:
>   Windows Event Log supports a subset of XPath 1.0. There are limitations to what functions work in the query. For instance, you can use the `position`, `Band`, and `timediff` functions within the query but other functions like `starts-with` and `contains` are not currently supported.

Comment: Ok, so you're saying that '*' support is intended only for the Node Names and not for values?   I know that 'starts-with' and 'contains' are not supported

Comment: Correct ________

Answer (score 12):

Use Powershell

```
Get-EventLog -LogName "System" | ?{$_.Message -like "*YourSearchString*"} | Out-GridView
```

Comment: Not the best idea if you are looking to make this fast